# Is my code SQL Injection Proof?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sql-injection

Is this SQL Injection proof? Or at least okay? I got this off online so I could really use some help. I am currently building quite a large program and I decided to add a login page if I ever felt like making it paid. Please help!

```
if (txt_UserName.Text == "" || txt_Password.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please provide a Username and Password");
    return;
}

try
{
    // Create SqlConnection
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_Login where UserName = @username and Password = @password", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txt_UserName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txt_Password.Text);

    con.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adapt.Fill(ds);

    con.Close();

    int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

    // If count is equal to 1, than show frmMain form
    if (count == 1)
```

Comment: It isn't. You should use prepared statements. Read about it in the SqlConnector docs. I'm on my mobile, so I can't post a complete answer now.

Comment: @SplittyDev How would a prepared statement provide any protection compared to this? It's just the same, but prepared, which in this case might not even be useful.

Comment: Note: Using DataSet for this kind of query is quite bad. They are slow and memory hungry and you would be better just using `DataReader`

Comment: I just want to point out that this is off-topic because the code is actually working. I'd suggest you try to ask it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ which is meant for those types of posts...

Comment: It ***IS*** perfectly safe from SQL injection, since you're using a **properly parametrized SQL query**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is SQL Injection proof. For ***Plain SQL Query***, I personally like to use [Dapper ORM](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) which is used in StackOverflow.

It is basically same, but a lot less code and returns strongly-typed value instead of DataSet.

For example,

```
public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

User user;
using (IDbConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    user = cnn.Query<User>(
        "Select UserName, Password from tbl_Login where UserName=@username and Password=@password",
        new { username = txt_UserName.Text, password = txt_Password.Text })
        .SingleOrDefault();
}

if (user != null)
{
    // Do someting
}
```

***FYI***: It seems that you are storing Plain Password. If so, it is not a good practice. Instead, you want to store salted hashed password.